# Is there a way to run Python scrips in Atom with multiple versions of Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, path, atom-editor

I am using the Atom text editor to write Python programs. I usually begin a new script with the command `atom script_name.py`, and the Atom text editor opens. You can execute scripts with the package `script` with the command `cmd+i`. (See https://atom.io/packages/script)

There are situations when I would like to use `Python 2.7` and other situations when I prefer to use `Python 3.4`.

From my understanding, the only way to do this is to manually change the `$PATH` for the version of Python. In my case, the path for `Python 3.4` is `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4`
and the path for `Python 2.7` is `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7`.

Is there another way to do this besides manually changing `$PATH` each time? Is there another package I could be using?

EDIT: Maybe there is some confusion. I think you should be able to run in Atom a script using `python2.7` and `python3.4`. In the command line, one would simply do `python script.py` for `python2.7` and for `python3.4` run `python3 script.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both versions in your `PATH` at the same time if the executables have different names.

In my case I have:

python 2.7 (`python`): `/usr/bin/python`

python 3 (`python3`): `/usr/local/bin/python3`

Comment: This I understand, but given my set-up above, which version of Python will Atom use to execute scripts?

Comment: Use the `Script: Run Options` option from the package `script`. Apparently you can create "profiles" to run with both versions. See under session __Usage__ on the [package page](https://atom.io/packages/script).

Comment: Thanks for the help! This works well, as users can simply use the commands they already use via the command line.